# Meaning of the Symbol of single apostrophe(') in Scala using Anonymous function under withColumn function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, anonymous-function

My questions is:

In line number 5: What is the operation of the symbol of single apostrophes(')? Cannot understand very clearly that how withColumn function is working over here. Also Please elaborate how it is displaying like these Column order- |id         |text    |upper   |.

Code:

```
 1. val dataset = Seq((0, "hello"),(1, "world")).toDF("id","text")
 2. val upper: String => String =_.toUpperCase
 3. import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
 4. val upperUDF = udf(upper)
 5. dataset.withColumn("upper", upperUDF('text)).show
```

Output:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|id       |text     |upper    |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 0       | hello   |HELLO    |
| 1       | world   |WORLD    |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: `withColumn` creates a new column if the first argument passed to it doesn't already exist in a dataframe. If it does, it overwrites the existing column. `'text` is used to select the column named `text`. In place of `'text`, you can also use `$"text"` or `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(text)`. The order is like that because the first two columns are `id` and `text` and `withColumn` is _appending_ a column which will get added at the end. You need to go through the documentation first. You'll find lots of interesting things there.

Comment: @philantrovert Thanks a lot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `'` symbol in Scala is syntax sugar for creating an instance of the `Symbol`. class. From the documentation

> For instance, the Scala term `'mysym` will invoke the constructor of the Symbol class in the following way: Symbol("mysym").

So when you write `'text`, the compiler expands it into `new Symbol("text")`.

There is additional magic here, since Sparks `upperUDF` method requires a `Column` type, not a `Symbol`. But, there exists an implicit in scope defined in `SQLImplicits` called `symbolToColumn` which converts a symbol to a column:

```
implicit def symbolToColumn(s: Symbol): ColumnName = new ColumnName(s.name)
```

If we extract away all the implicits and syntax sugar, the equivalent would be:

```
dataset.withColumn("upper", upperUDF(new Column(new Symbol("text").name))).show
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the line number 5. Please

Comment: @BhaskarDas I was just adding information to the answer. See it now.